# How to check login nave VS a field from database table in PHP?

Tags: php, openldap

How can I figure out the login information for a user.

I want php to return domain\username for the windows then i will do a check in the database if it exists or not if it exists then it is validated.

In ASP.NET this function Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString() does exactly what i need but i need this is PHP

How can i do this is PHP? I heard of LDAP but I can't get it to work and I am not sure if LDAP will do the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want `http://domain.com/username`

you must have to use `.htaccess` file. read more about [htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

**Edited**

after login, just store username to one variable and say it `$username`, now pass that username to your index.php file like...

```
index.php?username=$username
```

rewrite this URL via htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

now you can access it `domain.com/username`

Comment: Simit, I have used this file before to re-write urls and things like that but how can i use this file to give me the windows login for a user?  so if my user name is 'jsmith' and my domain is organization.com  then I need php to detect organization.com\jsmith

Comment: The whole purpose is not to login. so automatically find out the user name from windows authentication then match it in the database. So local users wont need to log in. I guess what i am trying to get to in this variable to work  $_SERVER["LOGON_USER"]; .   when i use this varibale it does not work and i am runing PHP 6.0